# Looking for two terms from law vocabulary

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, technical, legalese

I'm looking for two technical words used in law:

1. Someone who accepts the law, they will try to do the best things in any situation.
2. The opposite of number one, they reject any law and at every chance will run away from it.

for example in the law vocab, "ALIBI" means : A defence where an accused alleges that at the time when the offence was committed, he was elsewhere.

I'm looking for words like that! like "objection" or ...

Comment: Could you give examples to illustrate the two scenarios please?

Comment: This question really would be better answered with some clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Law-abiding
2. Recidivist, anarchist, rebel, or criminal, depending on the context.

Comment: thnx bro, are sure about that, i don't want the general word , i want technical word for that !

Comment: @Sam *Law-abiding* as in *law-abiding citizen* is the correct term. Criminal, offender, convict, recidivist could all be used in legal contexts. Of those, you probably are looking for recidivist. That means repeat offender and is used in legal contexts only. Anarchist is a political term.

Comment: thank you so much , is there any dictionary for the law vocab? how we can be sure about that?

Comment: @Sam:  Check out thelawdictionary.org.  It may help you with legal terms.  You can also google the words "law" and "dictionary" and perhaps "definition" and you should get quite a few hits.

Answer (score 2):

> For number 1:

- a person of *bona fides*
- a law-abiding citizen

> For number 2:

- a *tortfeasor*, or an habitual *tortfeasor*
- a malefactor
- a person of *mala fides*
- a person of *dolus malus*
- an antinomianist (though it is used primarily in a religious or ethical/moral context to mean a person who is against laws and regulations; in particular, a person who thinks the more he breaks the law the better, figuring "the more I sin the more God's grace will abound toward me.").
- a delinquent
- an incorrigible

Answer (score 2):

There are many words for each but the most evocative are:

1. law-abiding
2. scofflaw